# Launching an application from another application

Tags: java, android, launch

This code is meant to simply launch an application in Android. Adding ComponentName pack to launchApplication creates an error elsewhere and I can't seem to solve the problem without creating another.

```
case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP:
            MyPackageInfo pack = (MyPackageInfo) list.getExpandableListAdapter().
   getGroup(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition));
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                LauncherIconCreator.createLauncherIcon(getActivity(), pack);
                break;
            case 1:
                LauncherIconCreator.launchApplication(getActivity(), pack.package_name);
                break;
            }
        }




public static void launchApplication(Context context, String name) {
        Intent packageIntent = LauncherIconCreator.getActivityIntent(pack);
        Toast.makeText(context, String.format(context.getText
       (R.string.starting_application).toString(), name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.startActivity(packageIntent);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error say?

Comment: launchApplication() in LauncherIconCreator cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:
 
context:
Context
getActivity()  
pack:
android.content.ComponentName
pack.package_name  (java.lang.String)
name:
String

Comment: I can't tell what that says, but your parameters look okay in the question

Comment: I should also add that this error only appears once pack is able to be called successfully in the second snippet.

Comment: What do you mean able to be called? That is a compilation error, so if something does not work properly, you have different variable types as the error states